# Discover utility not finding component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, installation, front-end, discover

I'm developing a component and Joomla can't find it using the Discover utility. This is my component xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" method="upgrade" version="3.5">
  <name>com_bowling</name>

  <files folder="site">
    <folder>views</folder>
  </files>

  <administration>
  </administration>
</extension>
```

This is a frontend only component so there are no admin files. I've placed this XML file in `/administrator/components/com_bowling` folder. Currently using Joomla version 3.10.11.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the name of the XML file?

Comment: @Sharky com_bowling.xml

Answer (score 0):

Discover install does not seem to work with `com_`-prefixed manifest files. The file name must be `bowling.xml` in your case.

Comment: that didn't work.

Comment: Strange, it worked for me. Did you click "Discover" button again?